# absolute positioned img, jquery not reacting on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making images gallery and I want to show delete icon on image. I made div containter for image and icon with relative position and icon img with position absolute. But jquery `.click` and `.on('click',function(){...});` not working. Here is my code (I'm using blueimp-gallery):

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img class="delete" src="/img/delete1.png" value="68">
    <a href="/images/018ce3de8.jpg" title="" data-gallery="">
        <img src="/images/thumbs/018ce3de8.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.delete {
    height: 16px!important;
    width: 16px!important;
    top: 10px;
    left: 224px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('.delete').click( function() {
    alert( 'click' );
});
```

When `.delete` is set changed another class it works. Why it's not working with this absolute positioned div? When I hover `.delete` div mouse icon is changing so it's on top.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/nm6wmgL1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the DOM to fully load before you attach the event handler.
Change your javascript like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```